# Minimum polynomial and Isomorphic Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

I wish to show that if $α$ has minimum polynomial $t^2− 2$ over ℚ and β has minimum polynomial $t^2 − 4t + 2$ over ℚ, then the fields ℚ(α) and ℚ(β) are
isomorphic. I know if $u,v$ have different minimal polynomials $p_u,p_v\in F[X]$, then $F(u)$ is not isomorphic to $F(v)$ as fields, but I am not sure about the method to prove the first statement.

Comment: What is the solution of $t^2-4t+2=0$?

Comment: 2 ±√2 is the solution

Comment: And for $t^2-2$?

Comment: @Homaniac So it has a $\sqrt2$ in it!

Comment: ±√2 is the solution

Comment: You say: "I know if $u,v$ have different minimal polynomials $p_u,p_v\in F[X]$, then $F(u)$ is not isomorphic to $F(v)$ as fields". Why? I think you are confused,

Comment: Yes got that result from another page and yep I'm confused~